# Why does this test using FakeAsync just hang on the "await" even though the future has completed?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I'm trying to write a test using FakeAsync but it seems to hang on my `await`s. Here's a stripped down example:

```dart
  test('danny', () async {
    await FakeAsync().run((FakeAsync async) async {
      print('1');
      final a = Future<bool>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5))
          .then((_) => print('Delayed future completed!'))
          .then((_) => true);

      print('2');
      async.elapse(const Duration(seconds: 30));
      // Tried all this too...
      // async.flushMicrotasks();
      // async.flushTimers();
      // async.elapse(const Duration(seconds: 30));
      // async.flushMicrotasks();
      // async.flushTimers();
      // async.elapseBlocking(const Duration(seconds: 30));

      print('3');
      await a;

      print('4');
      expect(1, 2);
    });
  });
```

This code outputs:

```
1
2
Delayed future completed!
3
// hangs and never prints '4'
```

The `async.elapse` call is allowing the future to be completed, but it still hangs on `await a`. Why?

Comment: From my understanding it mocks the behavior of the event loop. So I don't think you can use await, as you need to flush the event loop after the await call

Comment: It may be related to how "await" wraps the future in a Future.value, so even if the awaited future is already completed, the await is still locking

Comment: Yeah, that was the conclusion I ended up at. I managed to work around it by wrapping it with a function that just contiually flushes the microtask queue until the future completes (see my answer). I don't know if it's a good way to do this, but it helps illustrate what's going on.

Comment: An alternative would be to use "then". Since the call is synchronous due to it being mocked, we can store the result of "then" in a variable of the main function.

Comment: I think if you don't await it, the tests could end up passing before the code has finished (similar to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60675). It also just feels a bit weird to not be able to use await without hanging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to occur because although the `Future` is completed, the `await` call requires the microtask queue to be processed in order to continue (but it can't, since nobody is calling `async.elapse` after the `await`).

As a workaround, contiually pumping the microstask queue while the function is running seems to work - for example calling this function in place of `FakeAsync.run`:

```dart
/// Runs a callback using FakeAsync.run while continually pumping the
/// microtask queue. This avoids a deadlock when tests `await` a Future
/// which queues a microtask that will not be processed unless the queue
/// is flushed.
Future<T> runFakeAsync<T>(Future<T> Function(FakeAsync time) f) async {
    return FakeAsync().run((FakeAsync time) async {
    bool pump = true;
    final Future<T> future = f(time).whenComplete(() => pump = false);
    while (pump) {
        time.flushMicrotasks();
    }
    return future;
    }) as Future<T>;
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve this, when the time the future `a` needs to resolve is unknown?

Comment: The solution I gave was not dependant on the time to resolve `a`. It just pumps repeatedly until the future completes.

Comment: @DannyTuppeny Thanks a bunch for this. Although I have to add: isn't this a bizarre way of handling this package? Like, we, as consumers, are required to manage this `flushMicrotasks` manually? Not even docs to mention that this flush is never called if not explicitly like you've done. Also, why not suggest this as the default behavior for the `fake_async` package?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `await` does not work inside `fakeAsync`, so you are stuck with `Future.then()` and friends.

However you can very easily wait for all Futures to complete by calling `time.elapse()`and `time.flushMicrotasks()`.

```
test('Completion', () {
  fakeAsync((FakeAsync time) {
    final future = Future(() => 42);
    time.elapse(Duration.zero);

    expect(future, completion(equals(42)));
    time.flushMicrotasks();
  });
});
```

Comment: "It seems that `await` does not work inside `fakeAsync`, so you are stuck with `Future.then()` and friends." No, that makes no sense. `await` is syntactic sugar for using `Future.then()` and friends.